# How to combine data according to timestamps?

Tags: matlab, indexing, sum, timestamp, benchmarking

I have a series of text files containing data with two separate timestamps and would like to find out the sum of all values at a given time. The files may have different amounts of rows, but always three columns: `value timestamp1 timestamp2`, with entries such as

```
6.2 1 4 
4.3 2 9 
7.2 3 10
```

or

```
1.2 2 3 
0.3 3 9 
0.1 5 12
```

Below is an explanation of how the output is formed:

1. The timestamps from the two inputs are unified into a vector of unique values (so for the above example `{1,2,3}∪{2,3,5} -> {1,2,3,5}` or `{4,9,10}∪{3,9,12} -> {3,4,9,10,12}`).
2. For every unique timestamp a data point is selected from each of the inputs such that:

   - If the queried timestamp is lower than the smallest available one, the first data value is taken.
   - Otherwise, the data value having a lower or equal timestamp is taken.
3. The two values are summed and the next unique timestamp is processed (if available).

If I apply this algorithm on the example data above using `timestamp1`, I would get:

```
7.4 1  %6.2+1.2
5.5 2  %4.3+0.3
7.5 3  %7.2+0.3
7.3 5  %7.2+0.1
```

and for `timestamp2`:

```
7.4 3  %6.2+1.2
7.4 4  %6.2+1.2
4.6 9  %4.3+0.3
7.5 10 %7.2+0.3
7.3 12 %7.2+0.1
```

I think I need to do something with [time series](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/time-series-objects.html) so for that I already have the following converter code:

```
logs = dir('log1/*.txt');
k=1
for log = logs' 

    t{k}=timeseries(load(log.name))
    k=k+1
end
```

I guess the next step would be something like `sum(t)` but that doesn't work. Does anybody know how to combine them like the above?

For anyone interested these are cpu and realtime timestamps (since algorithm start), for measuring the performance of an algorithm.

Comment: I don't see how you go from two sets of three timestamps to four or five timestamps, and what's happening to the second and third columns.

Comment: @Steve the final set up timestamps will be the same size as the number of unique timestamps in the input data. Also the first column is value rather then timestamps.

Comment: Okay, I see which rows you've added in to the new data; I don't see why the first row of *combined relative to timestamp1* is `6.2 + 1.2` (`1.2` is not from older data), and the last row is `7.2 + 0.1` (combined with one older data point, but not all).

Comment: @Steve the first one is because quite simply I need a value for the first dataset and the first datapoint of the missing dataset will have to do, the second one doesn't seem weird to me, at moment 5 we have the last row for both datasets.

Comment: @Steve the 5 comes from the second dataset, specifically this line 0.1 5 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, the *two different timestamps* is a red herring - you could define your problem for one timestamp, ignoring the other.

As I understand it, you want to:

- consider all the times which appear in both data sets (here, consider just the *timestamp1*, is `[1,2,3,5]`)
- interpolate/extrapolate using the nearest neighbour for any missing data points in both lists: (`5` is missing from the first dataset, `1` is missing from the second dataset)
- Return the sum of the values with the missing points filled.

Without the reading operations, this is how I see your processing:

```
times1 = [1,2,3];
values1 = [6.2, 4.3, 7.2];

times2 = [2, 3, 5];
values2 = [1.2, 0.3, 0.1];

all_times = union(times1, times2)';
values1_interp = interp1(times1, values1, all_times, 'nearest', 'extrap');
values2_interp = interp1(times2, values2, all_times, 'nearest', 'extrap');
v_sum = values1_interp + values2_interp;
```

Can see the results:

```
>> table(v_sum, all_times)

ans = 

    v_sum    all_times
    _____    _________

    7.4      1        
    5.5      2        
    7.5      3        
    7.3      5
```

If instead we were to use

```
times1 = [4, 9, 10];
times2 = [3, 9, 12];
```

then we would get

```
>> table(v_sum, all_times)

ans = 

    v_sum    all_times
    _____    _________

    7.4       3       
    7.4       4       
    4.6       9       
    7.5      10       
    7.3      12
```

**Edit:** From the [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303825/in-matlab-how-do-i-combine-data-with-timestamps#comment81572468_47310899), we don't quite want nearest neighbour, but instead a *most recent neighbour*, but we use the first point if we are extrapolating a time before our times have begun (e.g., extrapolating `values1` to time `1` when our `times1` is `[2,3,4]`): For this you could use something like

```
function [vq] = interp_left(x, v, xq)
%INTERP_LEFT Interpolate to the left-nearest point
% x must be sorted.
vq = nan(size(xq));
for ii = 1:length(xq)
  % Find the index in x nearest to xq, only considering smaller x
  [~,jj] = max(x(x<=xq(ii)));
  % Special case, there are no smaller x; extrapolate using [x(1),v(1)]
  if isempty(jj)
    vq(ii) = v(1);
  else
    vq(ii) = v(jj);
  end % if
end % for
end % function
```

then usage with

```
times1 = [1,2,3];
values1 = [6.2, 4.3, 7.2];

times2 = [2, 3, 5];
values2 = [1.2, 0.3, 0.1];

all_times = union(times1, times2)';
values1_interp = interp_left(times1, values1, all_times);
values2_interp = interp_left(times2, values2, all_times);
v_sum = values1_interp + values2_interp;
```

Comment: Almost, I'm looking for the previous datapoint rather then the nearest (except for the first where no previous datapoint exists).

Comment: @Thijser I've added an interpolation function with the behaviour you've described.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it tomorrow, I'm done for today.

Answer (score 2):

I've been thinking about this quite some time, and finally came up with the solution below. Although it's not conceptually different from [Steve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47310899/3372061), at least it's vectorized :)

```
%% Preparations:
%{
In the same folder:

data1.txt:
6.2 1 4
4.3 2 9
7.2 3 10

data2.txt:
1.2 2 3
0.3 3 9
0.1 5 12
%}
```

```
function out = q47303825(fname1,fname2,whichStamp)
%% Input handling:
if nargin < 3
  whichStamp = 1;
end
if nargin == 0
  fname1 = 'data1.txt';
  fname2 = 'data2.txt';
end
%% Reading the data :
d1 = dlmread(fname1,' ');
d2 = dlmread(fname2,' ');
%% Preallocation:
out = union(d1(:,whichStamp+1), d2(:,whichStamp+1)) .* [NaN,1];
%% Modifying the data slightly to allow vectorization:
d1 = [d1(1), -Inf, -Inf; d1; d1(size(d1,1)), +Inf, +Inf];
d2 = [d2(1), -Inf, -Inf; d2; d2(size(d2,1)), +Inf, +Inf];
%% Find indices:
[~,I1] = min(d1(:,whichStamp+1) <= out(:,2).',[],1);
[~,I2] = min(d2(:,whichStamp+1) <= out(:,2).',[],1);
I1 = I1-1; I2 = I2-1;
%% Generate final output:
out(:,1) = d1(I1) + d2(I2);
```